# Optimizing Laravel Query to get required data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following models in my Laravel project

1. Merchant
2. Deals
3. Deal Votes
4. Deal Clicks
5. Deal Deal Types
6. Merchant Rating

This is how my Merchants Model looks like

```
class Merchants extends Model
{
    //
    public function deals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deals', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }
}
```

Deals Model

```
class Deals extends Model
{
//
    public function clicks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Clicks', 'deal_id', 'deal_id');
    }
    public function merchants()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Merchants', 'deal_id', 'deal_id');
    }
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deal_votes', 'deal_id', 'deal_id');
    }
    public function deal_dealtypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deal_dealtypes', 'deal_id', 'deal_id');
    }
}
```

Merchant Rating Model

```
public function merchants()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Merchants', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }
```

For a specific Merchant Landing page, I am trying to get some Merchant info, deals tied to the merchant, count of votes and clicks for each Deal. This is what I have done so far

```
$merchant = Merchants::where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
                -> with('categories' ,'deals','deals.votes','deals.clicks', 'deals.deal_dealtypes')
                -> first();
```

This however is returning Merchant Info, Deal Info, All the Votes records tied to the Deal and all the clicks tied to each deal.

Attached sample data response I am getting

```html
{
merchant_id: 6605,
master_merchant_id: null,
skimlinks_id: null,
merchant_name: "Groupon",
network: "cj",
network_id: "",
network_notes: null,
dual_network: null,
related_merchants: null,
affiliate_link: "http://api.coupilia.com/merchants/?aid=1423&mid=6605",
skimlinks_url: null,
fmtcurl: null,
merchant_homepage_url: "www.groupon.com?z=dealpage",
status: null,
selected_status: null,
relationship_status: null,
primary_country: "US",
apofpo: null,
primary_category: null,
subcategories: null,
special_payment_options: null,
mobile_certified: null,
logos: "",
custom_logo: "https://res-5.cloudinary.com/dhhntbusx/image/upload/t_media_lib_thumb/v1475206550/Groupon-coupons_mzjdm8.jpg",
custom_description: null,
added: null,
lastupdated: null,
merchant_url_text: "groupon.com",
about: "",
primary_category_id: "43",
parent_merchant_id: null,
skimlinks_ids: null,
custom_merchant_name: null,
ship_to_countries: "",
created_at: "2016-10-07 08:04:12",
updated_at: "2016-10-07 08:04:12",
categories: {
id: 43,
slug: "social",
category_name: "Social",
category_url_name: "social",
category_parent_id: null,
category_grandparent_id: null,
created_at: "2016-10-07 08:04:03",
updated_at: "2016-10-07 08:04:03"
},
deals: [
{
deal_id: 875438,
merchant_name: "Groupon",
merchant_id: 6605,
status: null,
deal_text: "Save Up To 90% Off Local Restaurants, Shops, Events And More",
restrictions: "",
coupon_code: "",
deal_start_date: "1/31/2016",
deal_end_date: "11/6/2016",
discount_type: null,
deal_type: "deal",
affiliate_url: "",
final_sale_price: null,
was_price: null,
discount: null,
percent_off: null,
dollars_off: null,
network: null,
image: null,
skimlinks_url: null,
fmtcurl: null,
created: null,
lastupdated: null,
threshold: null,
rank: "3",
starred: null,
master_merchant_id: null,
brands: null,
local: null,
link_id: null,
direct_url: null,
pixel_html: null,
created_at: "2016-10-07 08:05:26",
updated_at: "2016-10-07 08:05:26",
votes: [
{
id: 2,
deal_id: 875438,
vote: 1,
user_id: 0,
uuid: "ad63d5a0-2582-11e6-9a1c-49da886e8d6c",
created_at: "2016-10-12 05:23:57",
updated_at: "2016-10-12 05:23:57"
},
{
id: 5,
deal_id: 875438,
vote: 1,
user_id: 0,
uuid: "bde41ea0-903c-11e6-b93b-51bc5393a427",
created_at: "2016-10-12 05:28:50",
updated_at: "2016-10-12 05:28:50"
}
],
clicks: [
{
id: 1,
tracking_id: null,
merchant_id: null,
deal_id: "875438",
user_id: null,
user_tracking_id: null,
referring_url: "http://trystin.app:8000/deals-coupons/groupon.com",
referring_domain: null,
page_type: null,
page_url: null,
utm_source: null,
utm_medium: null,
utm_term: null,
utm_campaign_id: null,
os: "OS X",
ip_address: "10.0.2.2",
browser: "Chrome",
initial_referring_domain: null,
referring_keyword: null,
deal_position: null,
click_type: null,
created_at: "2016-10-12 02:19:59",
updated_at: "2016-10-12 02:19:59"
},
{
id: 12,
tracking_id: null,
merchant_id: null,
deal_id: "875438",
user_id: null,
user_tracking_id: null,
referring_url: "http://trystin.app:8000/deals-coupons/groupon.com",
referring_domain: null,
page_type: null,
page_url: null,
utm_source: null,
utm_medium: null,
utm_term: null,
utm_campaign_id: null,
os: "OS X",
ip_address: "10.0.2.2",
browser: "Chrome",
initial_referring_domain: null,
referring_keyword: null,
deal_position: null,
click_type: null,
created_at: "2016-10-21 03:41:11",
updated_at: "2016-10-21 03:41:11"
},
{
id: 15,
tracking_id: null,
merchant_id: null,
deal_id: "875438",
user_id: null,
user_tracking_id: null,
referring_url: "http://trystin.app:8000/deals-coupons/groupon.com",
referring_domain: null,
page_type: null,
page_url: null,
utm_source: null,
utm_medium: null,
utm_term: null,
utm_campaign_id: null,
os: "OS X",
ip_address: "10.0.2.2",
browser: "Chrome",
initial_referring_domain: null,
referring_keyword: null,
deal_position: null,
click_type: null,
created_at: "2016-10-21 03:55:33",
updated_at: "2016-10-21 03:55:33"
},
{
id: 16,
tracking_id: null,
merchant_id: null,
deal_id: "875438",
user_id: null,
user_tracking_id: null,
referring_url: "http://trystin.app:8000/deals-coupons/groupon.com",
referring_domain: null,
page_type: null,
page_url: null,
utm_source: null,
utm_medium: null,
utm_term: null,
utm_campaign_id: null,
os: "OS X",
ip_address: "10.0.2.2",
browser: "Chrome",
initial_referring_domain: null,
referring_keyword: null,
deal_position: null,
click_type: null,
created_at: "2016-10-21 04:06:08",
updated_at: "2016-10-21 04:06:08"
}
],
deal_dealtypes: [
{
id: 1888,
deal_id: "875438",
dealtype_id: "3",
created_at: "2016-10-07 08:05:26",
updated_at: "2016-10-07 08:05:26"
}
]
},
}
```

I need some help with the following

1. Get limited fields and not all fields tied to Merchant
2. Get limited fields from deals object
3. Get Count of Votes and Clicks for each deal in the response

Answer (score 0):

To get limited fields you can use [`select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) function and to get counts you can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) function.

So your query will be as:

```
$merchant = Merchants::where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
                    ->select('id', 'name')
                    ->with(['deals' => function($q) {
                            $q->select('id', 'name')
                              ->with('votes','clicks', 'deal_dealtypes')
                              ->withCount('votes')
                              ->withCount('clicks');
                        }])
                   ->with('categories')
                   -> first();
```

Comment: I am getting an error message saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' . Not sure why

Comment: Using the code but now I am getting the following response. {
merchant_id: 6605,
deals: [ ]
} The deals are empty.

Comment: There can be a chance that there is no entry of deals in DB for merchant_id =  6605.

Comment: No, I if comment your part of ->with(['deals' => function($q) {
                            $q->select('id', 'name')
                                ->withCount('votes')
                                ->withCount('clicks');
                        }]) and I can see the deals tied to the merchant.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you try it one more chance.

Comment: Its not pulling the deals. If i do $merchant = Merchants::where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
                    ->select('merchant_id')->with ('deals')-> first(); I am getting merchant details and deals. If I do $merchant = Merchants::where('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
                    ->select('merchant_id')
                    ->with (['deals' => function ($q){
                        $q->select('deal_id', 'deal_text');
                    }])->first(); I am getting merchant but no deals. Looks like there is an issue in the with clause.